# Because of If statement cannot log in

Tags: java, swing, if-statement

I want to login to the system. When create my customers with ID and account number, I am trying to input them and want that if ID and account are connected - the dialog will be open.

when I created customer ID, in my constructor I converted it to String:

```
Customer(int id, String pps, String name, String surname, String birthday, String password){

        this.id = nextId.incrementAndGet();
        Integer.toString(this.id);
```

when I created account in another class, but for the customer, I did the same in my constructor (I converted account number to String):

```
public CustomerAccount(int accountNumber, double balance){

        Random n = new Random();
        this.accountNumber = 100000 + n.nextInt(900000);
        Integer.toString(this.accountNumber);
```

In my driver class, I have the button, and then, when I press the button, the dialogs should be open.

```
depositW.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                     JFrame frame = new JFrame(" ");
                     boolean found1 = false;
                     boolean found = false;


                     String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the ID number: ");         
                     for(Customer aCustomer: customers){
                         System.out.println("ID: " + a + " = " + aCustomer.getId());
                         if(a.equals(aCustomer.getId())){
                             BankInterface.setCurrentCustomer(aCustomer);
                             found1 = true;
                         }else{
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "There is no customer with this ID number", "Please try again", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                       }

                if(found1){      
                     String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the account number: ");   
                               for(CustomerAccount cu: BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts()){ 
                                   System.out.println("Account: " + a + " = " + cu.getAccountNumber());
                                   if(b.equals(cu.getAccountNumber())){

                                      BankInterface.setCurrentAccount(cu);
                                      found = true;
                                   }
                                }
                }

                if(found && found1){
                     new WithdrawDepositDialog(BankInterface.this, customers);
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The username or password is not correct", "Please try again", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
                  }
                    }
            });
```

When I test it, in my console window I have the following:
So it does not find the id, when it is running.

```
ID: 1 = 1
ID: 1 = 2
```

I am now sure, what is the mistake. I guess something wring in my if statement. What will be the possible solution in this problem?

---

**Updated code:**

```
String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the ID number: ");
for (Customer aCustomer: customers) {
    System.out.println("ID: " + a + " = " + aCustomer.getId());
    if (a.equals(aCustomer.getId())) {
        BankInterface.setCurrentCustomer(aCustomer);
        found1 = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "There is no customer with this ID number", "Please try again", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is working perfectly fine.

Your loop over all customer:

```
for(Customer aCustomer: customers){
```

does not terminate here:

```
if(a.equals(aCustomer.getId())){
     BankInterface.setCurrentCustomer(aCustomer);
      found1 = true;
}
```

Because found1 = true is not a loop condition. What you are missing here is a simple `break;` after this line.

Comment: `if(a.equals(aCustomer.getId())){
          BankInterface.setCurrentCustomer(aCustomer);
          found1 = true;
          break;` It is what I did. In my console again everything is fine. But it goes to dialog, which is saying that "There is no customer with this ID number"

Comment: You should not have a dialog open in this for loop at all. Assuming you have 10 entries. You are searching the 10th entry, so you will have 9 times a dialog ;)

Comment: Okey. I have it like in a proper order. It still shows that there is no customer with this id. String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the ID number: ");   ` for(Customer aCustomer: customers){ 
         System.out.println("ID: " + a + " = " + aCustomer.getId()); if(a.equals(aCustomer.getId())){
          BankInterface.setCurrentCustomer(aCustomer);
          found1 = true;
          break;
          }
        }if(!found1){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "There is no customer with this ID number", "Please try again", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);  }`

Comment: @Alex I have edited your post with this code. Please next time do it yourself, instead of having it posted on comments. It makes it easier to read.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will, next time. It still does not work, and I am not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

Your Customer constructor looks very suspicious:

```
Customer(int id, String pps, String name, String surname, String birthday, String password){
    this.id = nextId.incrementAndGet();
    Integer.toString(this.id);
```

After `Integer.toString(this.id);`, this.id is still an integer!

Therefore `a.equals(aCustomer.getId())` will never return true, since you are comparing a string `a` with an integer `aCustomer.getId()`

Comment: Oh, thank you that told me that. is it better to put this conversion outside the constructor? and if it is, then where? Because I think it could be my problem at the moment...

Comment: `Integer.toString(this.id)` returns a string - you have to store it somewhere. Something like `this.stringId = Integer.toString(this.id);` and then Customer.getId() should return the stringId

Comment: I did this. Still not work. I am not sure, at the reason and how to know, is it converts or not. First lime is  `aCustomer.setId(this.id);`  Then I store, as you suggested `String stringId = Integer.toString(this.id);  `  and then have my if statement `if(a.equals(aCustomer.getId()))`

Comment: Okey, I just changed everything to integer. this thing I understand better, so, it opens another dialog. Thank you!